# how to identify if ultrasonic pin is removed from circuit using python code

Tags: python, pi-2, sensor

this is the simple code to measure  distance using ultrasoinic sensor attached to reapberry-pi and by writing python script--

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 16

ECHO = 20


print "Distance Measurement In Progress"

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

while True:

GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
time.sleep(2)

GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

time.sleep(0.00001)

GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
    pulse_start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
    pulse_end = time.time()

pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round(distance, 2)
print "Distance:",distance,"cm"
```

use case is- I have to run this script only when all the pins of ultrasonic sensor is properly connected to the circuit and the raspberry-pi. 
so my question is, can we identify the pin connection before running the script?
or can we identify whether our hardware is working properly or not?

Answer (score 1):

Send a trigger.  If you do not get a response within a timeout period assume the device isn't present.

Comment: can u plz tell me how to send external trigger in raspberry-pi using python.

Comment: @andy I would send the trigger in the same way as the code does at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, unless you use an EEPROM chip (like Pi HATs [HAT specification](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats)) then you will be able to know what GPIO pins need to be setup, otherwise it's anyone's guess; unless you want to flat out ask the user in the code what pins they have configured (or get that information from [command line arguments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm))
i.e. add the following to your code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

TRIG = int(raw_input('What pin are you using for the trigger?  '))
ECHO = int(raw_input('What pin are you using for the echo?  '))

GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
```